# Prove that a complex series converges and find its sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve this problem but I've been unsuccessful so far.

(a) Prove that the series $z(1-z)+z^2(1-z)+z^3(1-z)+...$ converges for |z|<1

(b) Find its sum

Thank you

Comment: You haven't noticed that you can factor $1-z$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we are simply summing a geometric series with

$$(1-z)\sum_{k=1}^\infty z^n=(1-z)\frac{z}{1-z}=z$$

for $|z|<1$.

To show that it converges, note that

$$\sum_{n=1}^N z^n=\frac{z-z^{N+1}}{1-z}$$

Provided $|z|<1$, then $\lim_{N\to \infty}z^{N+1}=0$ and we are done!

Comment: Thank you for your help! I understand it now!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure. -Mark

Comment: Oh thank you for the information. Quick question: the book I'm using says that the sum of a geometric series is $1/(1-z)$ instead of $z/(1-z)$ Is this a special case?

Comment: Enrique, you're welcome.  If we start the series from $n=k\ge 0$ we see that for $|z|<1$ $$\sum_{n=k}^Nz^n=\frac{z^k-z^{N+1}}{1-z}\to \frac{z^k}{1-z}\,\,\text{as}\,\,N\to \infty$$So, if $k=1$, we get $\frac{z}{1-z}$ while if $k=0$, we get $\frac{1}{1-z}$